# Cartesian product of Locally connected spaces is locally connected iff each space is locally connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I need the proof of the Cartesian product of Locally connected spaces is locally connected iff each space is locally connected. I do have the left implication, as it is trivial using continuity and openness of the projection aplication. But I don't know how to do the right implication. I think that it can be done using induction for n = 2 and using the bases of the locally connected spaces.
The problem statment is as follows: Proof that for locally connected spaces $X_{i}$ non-empty, $X_{1} \times X_{2}... \times X_{n}$ is locally connectes iff $X_{1}, X_{2}, .. , X_{n}$ is locally connected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though we can guess it, it is not directly clear from your post what you call left and right implications. Moreover, beware of the emptyset for the "left implication".

Comment: You should add that the products you are considering are *finite* (and that all factors are non-empty), as an arbitrary product of non-empty spaces is locally connected, iff each factor is locally connected and all but finitely many factors are connected. Of course, if (at least) one factor is empty, the product is locally connected,